# How can i programmatically change the color of certain elements in an SVG file using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, svg, swiftui

I am creating a travel app in swiftui where users can keep track of which countries they have visited. I want to do this by allowing users to select which countries they have visited from a list and then display a svg of a world map that fills the visited countries blue. Here is an example: [app example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lnbj.jpg)

Below is an example of the svg file. Every path represents a country and has an id. I want to be able to find a path by it's id and change the color of it to blue. It's pretty easy to do this in javascript but i'm having great trouble finding any documentation online for swift.

`<path d="m 479.68275,331.6274 -0.077,0.025 -0.258,0.155 -0.147,0.054 -0.134,0.027 -0.105,-0.011 -0.058,-0.091 0.006,-0.139 -0.024,-0.124 -0.02,-0.067 0.038,-0.181 0.086,-0.097 0.119,-0.08 0.188,0.029 0.398,0.116 0.083,0.109 10e-4,0.072 -0.073,0.119 z" title="Andorra" id="AD" />`

I am using SVGKit (https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) to import the svg into my swiftui view. Below is the code that I already have to simple display the svg in my view.

My SVGImageView struct:

```
struct SVGImageView: View {
    let svgImage: SVGKImage

    init(svgImage: SVGKImage) {
        self.svgImage = svgImage
    }

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: svgImage.uiImage)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }
}
```

And inside the swiftui view:

```
if let svgImage = SVGKImage(named: "world") {
     SVGImageView(svgImage: svgImage)
          .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.85)
          .padding(.top)
}
```

Here is what this currently looks like: [my app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDUWx.png)

I haven't tried anything yet, i've been looking at different repo's on github but haven't had any luck so I decided to ask it here.

Comment: I once did something like this, but for places in China only. I downloaded a geojson file containing all the areas of the map, as geojson "features". Each feature has a name associated with it so it is easy to identify. (Not sure if svg supports something like that) Then I basically hand-drew each area using the geometry info in the geojson data.

Comment: [Here is some geojson data I found for the whole world map](https://gist.github.com/markmarkoh/2969317).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once did something similar to this before, but only for China. I used GeoJSON data instead of SVG, because I couldn't find a nice SVG for China's map. Another advantage of using GeoJSON is that you can easily change the map projection, and that the file size can be a lot smaller.

Here's the drawing code I used, adapted for SwiftUI. I used the [CodableGeoJSON](https://github.com/guykogus/CodableGeoJSON) package just for adding `Codable` GeoJSON types. You can totally write those types yourself by examining the structure of the JSON, so you don't have to use the package if you don't want.

```
struct CountryProperties: Codable {
    let name: String
}

typealias MapFeatureCollection = GeoJSONFeatureCollection<MultiPolygonGeometry, CountryProperties>
struct GeoJSONMapDrawer {
    let featureCollection: MapFeatureCollection?
    
    let colorDict: [GeoJSONFeatureIdentifier: Color]
    
    func drawMap(borderColor: Color, borderWidth: CGFloat, size: CGSize, context: GraphicsContext) {
        func transformProjectedPoint(_ point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
            point
                .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: size.width, y: size.height))
        }
        
        guard let featureCollection = self.featureCollection else { return }
        let features = featureCollection.features
        for feature in features {
            guard let multipolygon = feature.geometry?.coordinates else { continue }
            var multiPolygonPath = Path()
            let fillColor = colorDict[feature.id ?? ""] ?? .clear
            for polygon in multipolygon {
                let firstLinearRing = polygon.first!
                for (index, position) in firstLinearRing.enumerated() {
                    if index == 0 {
                        multiPolygonPath.move(to:
                            transformProjectedPoint(project(long: position.longitude, lat: position.latitude))
                        )
                    } else {
                        multiPolygonPath.addLine(to:
                            transformProjectedPoint(project(long: position.longitude, lat: position.latitude))
                        )
                    }
                }
                multiPolygonPath.closeSubpath()
            }
            context.fill(multiPolygonPath, with: .color(fillColor))
            context.stroke(multiPolygonPath, with: .color(borderColor), lineWidth: borderWidth)
        }
        print("Done!")
    }
    
    // this converts a longitude and latitude into a coordinate in a unit square
    func project(long: Double, lat: Double) -> CGPoint {
        let lowestLongitude: Double = -180
        let longitudeRange: Double = 360
        // the top and bottom of the map needs to be truncated,
        // because of how the mercator projection works
        // here I truncated the top 10 degrees and the bottom 24 degrees, as is standard
        let lowestLatitudeMercator: Double = mercator(-66)
        let latitudeRangeMercator: Double = mercator(80) - mercator(-66)
        let projectedLong = CGFloat((long - lowestLongitude) / longitudeRange)
        let projectedLat = CGFloat(1 - ((mercator(lat) - lowestLatitudeMercator) / latitudeRangeMercator))
        return CGPoint(x: projectedLong, y: projectedLat)
    }
    
    func mercator(_ lat: Double) -> Double {
        asinh(tan(lat * .pi / 180))
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, I drew the map using the [mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection), simply because the longitude doesn't need to change at all.

Then you can draw this with a SwiftUI `Canvas`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Canvas(rendersAsynchronously: true) { context, size in
            // as an example, I coloured Russia green
            let drawer = GeoJSONMapDrawer(featureCollection: loadGeojson(), colorDict: [
                // the keys in this dictionary corresponds to the "id" property in each feature
                "RU": .green
            ])
            drawer.drawMap(borderColor: .black, borderWidth: 1, size: size, context: context)
        }
        // from a quick google, 1.65 is apparently best for a mercator map
        .aspectRatio(1.65, contentMode: .fit)
    }
    
    func loadGeojson() -> MapFeatureCollection {
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "world", withExtension: "json")!)
        return try! JSONDecoder().decode(MapFeatureCollection.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

The GeoJSON file I used is: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/markmarkoh/2969317/raw/15c2e3dee7769bb77b62d2a202548e7cce039bce/gistfile1.js Note that there is the extra `var countries_data =` at the start of the file, which you should remove.

Output:

[image]

Comment: worked perfectly!